# wordpress plugins doesn't dispaly its content properly

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using wordpress 3.8 and I'm facing a problem with it, as It displays its images in a wrong way with the initial/first load. all the images display in vertical line view instead of thumbnail grid view. and I have to refresh the page to be displayed in the right view.
Does anyone have any idea about this?

this next two images display the issue, 
this issue occurred with two plugins which I use ( NextGEN Gallery by Photocrati ) and (Page Builder by SiteOrigin ).

expected
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2CDnkQhsAyMd294cnk4eGw4cjQ/edit

reality
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2CDnkQhsAyMcFFpRnB4VjdNVms/edit

Comment: Those links are private

Comment: Your links are privates! We can't see it.

Comment: sorry, check it out now!